# How to get json url from other json url in angular js

Tags: json, angularjs

```
JSON URL : https://api.github.com/users/odetocode
```

This json url contains url's of another json data. how i can hit another url from this url to get data and fetch it to the html

```
  var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal,$http)  {
  var url = "https://api.github.com/users/odetocode?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http.jsonp(url)    .
  success(function(post, status, headers, config) 
  { $scope.data = post; 
   $scope.users= post.data;
  $scope.followers_url= post.data.followers_url;
  }) .
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
  alert("no data found");

   });

});
```

How i can hit another url from this json file in angular js. if i want to check how many followers and following of this user.How i can do it.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING

Comment: I am not shouting, i just ask a question for help..

Comment: ALL CAPS, in print, is shouting

Comment: Satnam, I see that it's your first question. Using all caps is indeed not recommended. You have a link so as to edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing known as *Json url*. What you have is an url, that returns content represented in json when requested. Anyway, you can call a second url in the success callback of your first request. Something like the following:

```
$http.jsonp(url).success(function(post, status, headers, config) { 
    // ...
    // you can make a second $http call here,
    // but it is nicer to sequence a call to another 'then' (see below)
})
```

I'll advise you to use `then` instead of `success` and `error`, which are deprecated as of angular 1.4.4:

```
$http.jsonp(url)
    .then(function (httpResponse) {
        // the body of the http call is in httpResponse.data
        // ...
        return nextObject;
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        // make call to the followers url
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle errors
    });
```

The object returned by the first *then callback function* (here `nextObject`), will be the input data of the second *then callback function*.